# CSRF Protection in Lumen, Exception From Helper Function

Tags: laravel, lumen

According to the documentation for Laravel Lumen, [it's possible to make use of the CSRF helper function to generate a CSRF token](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-protection). However, when I go ahead and use the `csrf_field` function or the `csrf_token` function, I am presented with an error message:

> `Call to undefined function csrf_field()`

and

> `Call to undefined function csrf_token()`

respectively.

#### Research

It would appear as though some people are saying CSRF protection is not a part of Lumen, but since it's listed by the documentation I'd assume it is.

It's fairly possible I've overlooked something rather simple. Do I somehow need to tell Lumen that I'd like to use this helper specifically? Anyhow, any pointers in the right direction would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lumen doesn't have these helpers. You can check it by yourself by looking into the source code. So, you'll need to insert token manually:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ app('session')->token() }}">
```

Comment: Ah, that'd explain that! Still, however, there's an error, but now a new one for using the `app('session')->token()`. It states, `Class session does not exist`. Does that require for something to be registered somewhere?

Comment: @D.Ataro Lumen 5.2+ is made for APIs, so it looks like you need to install session related packages manually. I can see sessions related code in the source code (including `token()`), so when you'll be able to use the code from my answer and you'll install and register session package.